# ie7 does not execute loaded script with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, internet-explorer-7

on my main page i have js function

```
function loadNext(last){
    var index = parseInt($("#contentSupplier table tr:last td:first").html()) + 1;
    $.get("suppliernext.php?index=" + index + "&" + "last=" + last,      $("#supplierForm").serialize(), function(data){
        $("#contentSupplier table tr:last").after(data);

    });
}
```

and on page that is loaded suppliernext.php i have this code

```
<script>
    $("#loadnext").attr('onclick', 'loadNext(<?=$ps?>)');
<?php 
 if($i >= $rowcount)
{
    echo "$('#loadnext').hide();";
}
?>
</script>
```

this changes button on click function on the first page. 
ie7 executes this code but does not change the oncick function

in ie8 chrome and mozzila it is working correctly.
how can i make it work in ie7?

Comment: By the way, always use parseInt with the base 10: parseInt(value, 10) - there are input strings that are not interpreted with base 10... e.g. parseInt("010") is 8!

Answer (score 1):

Do not set onclick with attr! Use `on()`

```
$("#loadnext").off('click').on('click', function() {loadNext(<?=$ps?>);});
```

Comment: You might want to `.off('click')` first so you don't fire multiple `loadNext`es